# Match a string which does not contain a / but ends with .html

Tags: python, regex

I need a regex which will match all lines that end with .html with no `/` before the page: ex the first three lines but not the last one:

```
test1.html
test2.html
test3.html
https://example.com/index.html
```

I have `(.html)$` so far, and I don't want to do a simple contains `/`; just have a single regex. I was looking into negative lookahead in regex but its not cooporating with me

Comment: You don't mention your flavour of regex but perhaps `^(?!.*\/).*\.html$`

Comment: Your question is ambiguous - in the title you want no `/` whatsoever (a simple lookahead might help here) but in the content you only want it directly before. Please clarify.

Comment: not quite; "with no `/` before the page" doesn't mean directly before, just anywhere before the page;

Comment: @Nick Thanks!, yes that is closer to what I was looking for; I'll add a Python tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
(?<!/)\b[^/]+\.html$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/d2arDd/1/).